# Emberjs + ember-data find with param

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data, has-many, param

I'm trying to find a model based on a param like this :

```
this.store.find('slide', {slideCategory: category});
```

But it return : (Edit full stack trace)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at hi.extend.pushMany (ember-data.min.js?551b0279246c3:3)
at Dr.extend.load (ember-data.min.js?551b0279246c3:1)
at ember-data.min.js?551b0279246c3:1
at tryCatch (ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:46898)
at invokeCallback (ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:46910)
at publish (ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:46881)
at ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:27205
at Queue.invoke (ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:871)
at Object.Queue.flush (ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:936)
at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (ember.debug.js?551b0279246c3:741)
```

I'm running this code from an action in my SlideRoute.

Here is what my Slide model looks like

```
App.Slide = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    note: DS.attr('string'),
    slideCategory: DS.belongsTo('slideCategory')
});
```

And my SlideCategory model

```
App.SlideCategory = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    slides: DS.hasMany('slide', {async:true})
});
```

It's running with fixtures and here is one record :

```
{ 
    id: 1, 
    slideCategory: 1,
    title: 'Slide 1', 
    note: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget hendrerit lacus. Donec venenatis sagittis turpis a aliquet. Ut nec ipsum ac sem lobortis ultrices id eu ante. Aenean ut vehicula odio, non imperdiet risus. Aenean mattis diam nec nulla tincidunt, vitae vehicula dui vehicula.', 
}
```

I'm using ember 1.11 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.16

**EDIT**

All right, then it seems the problem was related to querying fixtures, which isnt supported by default by ember-data.

Let's say I go with the other option to get my slides and I use the following piece of code

```
this.store.find('slideCategory', category).then(function(slideCategory){
    slideCategory.get('slides').then(function(slides){

    }   
}
```

I would have expected the following piece of code to give me an array of slides on which I could loop but the object seems different.

This is what I get :

```
Class {
    __ember1427894067627: null
    __ember_meta__: Object
    __nextSuper: undefined
    canonicalState: Array[3]
        0: Class
        1: Class
        2: Class
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array[0]
    currentState: Array[3]
    isLoaded: true
    isPolymorphic: undefined
    length: 3
    record: Class
    relationship: ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$has$many$$ManyRelationship
    store: Class
    type: App.Slide
    __proto__: Class
```

This seems almost it but I don't really know how to loop through this object. It seems that the 3 elements in the canonicalState array are my 3 slides I'm looking for. When I open that class object I get exactly what a slide object would look like.

Sorry if this seems stupid but I'm new to ember and I could not find an answer to this question.

Comment: whats the value of  `category` in your route?

Comment: In that case it is 1. But even if I hardcode it to {slideCategory: 1} or {id: 'fixture-0'} it won't work. As long as there is a param added, the error shows up.

Comment: the fixture adapter doesn't support querying but that doesn't explain your error. could you paste the entire stacktrace?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at hi.extend.pushMany (ember-data.min.js?551b008dd7991:3)
    at Dr.extend.load (ember-data.min.js?551b008dd7991:1)
    at ember-data.min.js?551b008dd7991:1
    at tryCatch (ember.debug.js?551b008dd7991:46898)
    at invokeCallback (ember.debug.js?551b008dd7991:46910)
    at publish (ember.debug.js?551b008dd7991:46881)
    at ember.debug.js?551b008dd7991:27205
    at Queue.invoke (ember.debug.js?551b008dd7991:871)
    at Object.Queue.flush (ember.debug.js?551b008dd7991:936)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (ember.debug.js)

Comment: You should edit your post and put the stack trace there. It's pretty unreadable in the comments.

Comment: You are right! Updated

Comment: Don't use the minified version of ember-data it leaves out a lot of debugging information. The `pushMany` function should always receive an array and there are `Ember.assert` guards in place that will tell you with a nice error message whats going on. The minified version should be used in production not in tests.

Comment: This also explains why you don't see an error about the fixture adapter not supporting findQuery

Comment: Thanks albertjan, way better this way. At least I see what's going on!

Comment: I've added my comment as answer because there are bound to be more people running into this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the minified version of ember-data it leaves out a lot of debugging information. The pushMany function should always receive an array and there are `Ember.assert` guards in place that will tell you with a nice error message whats going on. The minified version should be used in production not in tests.

This also explains why you don't get an error message about the fixture adapter not supporting queries.